# Working with both Array and Record type in Azure Stream Analytics query

Tags: azure, stream, azure-stream-analytics

I'm new to Azure Stream Analytics query. My scenario is using Continuous Export to write Application Insight telemetry to Azure Blob storage and use Stream Analytics job to push data from Blob storage to Power BI. My json file has both Array and Request type as follows:

```html
{
 "request": [
  {
   "id": "|HLHUdGy4c3g=.556f8524_",
   "name": "HEAD Todos/Index",
   "count": 1,
   "responseCode": 200,
   "success": true,
   "url": "http://todoapp20183001.azurewebsites.net/",
   "urlData": {
    "base": "/",
    "host": "todoapp20183001.azurewebsites.net",
    "hashTag": "",
    "protocol": "http"
   },
   "durationMetric": {
    "value": 973023,
    "count": 1,
    "min": 973023,
    "max": 973023,
    "stdDev": 0,
    "sampledValue": 973023
   }
  }
 ],
 "internal": {
  "data": {
   "id": "124c5c1c-0820-11e8-a590-d95f25fd3f7f",
   "documentVersion": "1.61"
  }
 },
 "context": {
  "data": {
   "eventTime": "2018-02-02T13:50:39.591Z",
   "isSynthetic": false,
   "samplingRate": 100
  },
  "cloud": {},
  "device": {
   "type": "PC",
   "roleName": "todoapp20183001",
   "roleInstance": "RD0003FF6D001A",
   "screenResolution": {}
  },
  "user": {
   "isAuthenticated": false
  },
  "session": {
   "isFirst": false
  },
  "operation": {
   "id": "HLHUdGy4c3g=",
   "parentId": "HLHUdGy4c3g=",
   "name": "HEAD Todos/Index"
  },
  "location": {
   "clientip": "35.153.211.0",
   "continent": "North America",
   "country": "United States",
   "province": "Virginia",
   "city": "Ashburn"
  },
  "custom": {
   "dimensions": [
    {
     "_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors": "(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.0')"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Using the following query I can receive the expected output.

```html
WITH Request AS
(
    SELECT
        context.location.country as country,
        context.location.city as city,
        GetArrayElement(request,0) as requests
        FROM FromBlob
)

SELECT country, city, requests.name
FROM Request
```

Now I need to count all the request by city but I cannot seem to get it done with COUNT() and GROUP BY(). Is there a hint or reference to have a look in this case?

Comment: Can you post your attempt using Count and Group By, it should just work.

Comment: It does not work as the the column I want to group (country) does not exist.

Comment: I thought I would have to use JavaScript UDF to convert context.location.city to something before I can group by it. I'm unsure how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example to count the number of requests every 5 minutes.
Note that I had to add a time component to GROUB BY since your data is streaming data and you want to have the aggregate on a finite time.

```
WITH Request AS
(
SELECT
    context.location.country as country,
    context.location.city as city,
    GetArrayElement(request,0) as requests
    FROM iothub
)
SELECT country, city, count(requests.name)
FROM Request
group by country,city,SlidingWindow(minute,5)
```

Let me know if it works for you.